# SQLite detect data change between 2 rows

Tags: sqlite

For my research lab, I got some files with 500,000 entries of time, current, and voltage. I made a small program and dump all the entries into a SQLite table name gold100mV, which only has 3 columns: time, pA, and mV.

Is it possible to have a query that can compare rows and select? How does that query look like?

```
A query that detect a large value change and select the rows:
time        pA          mV
"1.7119"    "-1037.6"   "-101.746"
"1.7121"    "-1013.18"  "-101.776"
"1.7123"    "-1007.08"  "-101.715"
"1.7125"    "-1031.49"  "-101.837" // <-- Row of interest
"1.7127"    "1684.57"   "98.938"   // <-- Row of interest 
"1.7129"    "1196.29"   "99.0295"
"1.7131"    "1098.63"   "98.999"
"1.7133"    "1098.63"   "99.1516"
"1.7135"    "1062.01"   "99.1211"
```

Comment: yes, a query can select rows, and even (with extra effort) compare between rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM gold100mV g
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM gold100mV
  WHERE time > g.time AND pA > 0.9 * g.pA AND pA < 1.1 * g.pA
                      AND mV > 0.9 * g.mV AND mV < 1.1 * g.mV
)
```

You can also add and subtract a fix number instead of multiplication, whatever suits you. This would also select the last row, you would need to add an additional condition that the row cannot be the last one to only get the 2 rows.